# Which Cocoa UI element(s) should I use to display table like information - Mac OS X?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, user-interface

I want to display information of a person, it would look like:

```
   Name: Tom
Address: Long address, multi line,
         next line, Long address
Comment: some text
```

Please notice that each property may be multi-line text. The UI widget should auto resize height to fit the content, if new information is loaded.

In a web app, I know it can be done by layout with table. But how can I do this in a Cocoa Mac OS X app?

----- edit -----

To make this question more precise, assume this use case:

1. I have a view(widget, control) that display text.
2. The text is dynamically set.
3. The view's width must be(or is set to be) fixed.
4. The view's height automatically adjusted depending on the text, text may be wrapped into several lines.

My question is, is there a cocoa view to do this? I don't want to calculate and set the height programatically .

Answer (score 1):

You'd be looking for [NSTableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) if it's to be the same information for many (or more than 1) persons. Details can be found here: [About Table Views in OS X Applications](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000026i).
(some nice sample code on Apple's site as well, just follow the links in the class reference)

Or if you're just displaying information for 1 person you could use a bunch of [NSTextField s](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSTextField_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (the read-only flavour is called *Label* in Interface Builder).

Answer (score 0):

An NSTableView would probably suit best, but it depends on how you want your UI to look and feel.